# Git conflict while rebase

Tags: git, rebase, git-merge-conflict

My workgroup requires me to do a `git rebase master` on my current branch each time before pushing. However, when there are conflicts I find that I have major problems dealing with them.

I can resolve and update the affected files just fine, but after running `git add *` and `git commit -m "commitmsg"` Git refuses to carry out the `git rebase --continue`. Instead I see the following error message:

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

So I can only run `git rebase --abort` which undoes everything and sends me back to square one, or `git rebase --skip`, after which the same conflicts exist again.

Do I misunderstand Git here? What can I do to get out of that infinite loop of resolving the same conflicts over and over again?

EDIT : Running "git rebase --continue" after git add unfortunately produces the same conflicts again.

Comment: Don't commit anything until _after_ you've finished the entire rebase, and every commit has been reapplied (See Chris' answer below).  I don't know what should happen given what you did, but it's not the correct thing to do here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I can resolve and update the affected files just fine, but after running `git add *` and `git commit -m "commitmsg"` Git refuses to carry out the `git rebase --continue`.  Instead I see the following error message:
>
> > No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

Don't run `git commit` here. Just `git add` the resolved files (personally I avoid `*` or `.`), then run `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Just curious since you mentioned it- why do you avoid using `*` or `.` with `git add`. Is it just a safety precaution or is there another reason?

Comment: @chevybow, I like to know exactly what I'm adding. I'll use `git status` to see which files have been modified and check their diffs as I add them. I've seen people accidentally commit undesired changes with `git add .` enough times to consider it an antipattern, but of course if you're careful and especially if you're disciplined with your ignore patterns it can work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do that, the "git rebase --continue" produces the same conflicts again.

Comment: @edowy, as you go through a rebase you should see which commit is currently being rebased (e.g. "Patch failed at 0001 Commit message"). After resolving the conflicts and `git add`ing the resolved files, when you run `git rebase --continue`, do you see the same conflicts again _with another commit_ (e.g. "Patch failed at 0002 Another commit message")?

Comment: @chris I'm not sure to be honest. In the meantime, a "git rebase --skip" solved the issue ( I had tried that before and this time it worked without conflicts. No idea why) so I can't reproduce the problem anymore. We discussed this in our workgroup, and since others had similar issues, we now decided to only commit final versions of changes through branches that were created right before the commit, thereby reducing the number of rebases we need to do.